# How to show only the worksheet ranges where the user has modifying enabled?

Tags: microsoft-excel, permissions

Is there a manageable method to apply on a Protected & Shared Excel Workbook, that when it is opened, Excel just makes visible the worksheet(s) and/or ranges that the user was given permissions/enabled to edit/modify?

My goal is to maintain far away a complex Macro.

Comment: Have you looked into the 'scrollarea' attribute in VBA. You could set a private sub or function that sets the scroll area to what you want. Similar to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497766/limit-scrolling-in-excel-2003-vba) but with updated language [Here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/limit-scrolling-vba.htm) is some good info as well. What version of excel are you/they on? Also some more concrete details of what you have vs what you want would help us give specific directions to accomplish your goal

Comment: Raystafarian is right. Yet, I don't know if you can hide the worksheet(s) where user cannot write without VBA. Simply ask if you need this.

Comment: Will different users have different permissions? The fact that you have shared the workbook will create problems. For example, you cannot change protection levels on a shared workbook.